# Wrong rendering of inherited line-height

Tags: css

I have SPAN wrapped into another SPAN:

```
<span id="outer">
  <span id="inner">
    Some long text
  </span>
</span>
```

And CSS:

```
#outer {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    line-height: 30px;
}

#inner {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}
```

This variant renders exactly the same in Opera, Safari, Chrome, FF.
Text is rendered exactly 30px lines height.

If outer SPAN is set another font-family, for example Arial:

```
#outer {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

- Crome and Safari renders text as 31px line-height.
- FF - 30.5px line-height
- Opera - 30px (as expected)

Why this happens?

Note: this markup and styles is created by user in WYSIWYG editor.

- [JSFiddle - right rendering](http://jsfiddle.net/hFd63/)
- [JSFiddle - wrong rendering](http://jsfiddle.net/BbZLh/)

Comment: Different fonts - different `line-height`'s

Comment: Applying line-height:30px to inner span doesn't solves the problem.

Comment: If you compare two fonts, let's say in photoshop, you'll see that different fonts has different size. So I believe `line-height` suppose to be different as well.

Comment: It's obvious, but in this situation we have inner SPAN with text and styles applied to it (font-size, family, line-height), and i can't understand why outer SPAN alters inner SPAN rendering.

Comment: how do you measure line-height? From which point to which? Where is the value of 30.5px coming from?

Comment: Screenshot in photoshop. From bottom to bottom of letters in consequtive lines. By 30.5 i mean odd lines has 30px and even lines has 31px. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the image below, you will notice that both fonts have different baseline heights.  It appears that Times New Roman is about 2px shorter than Arial.

I'm not an expert on the font rendering engines, but my best guess as to what is happening is that the 1-2px additional pixels applied to the #outer is caused by Arial being 2px taller.

Even though the font within the #inner is Times New Roman, the rendering still has an affect on the outer div due to it being set as Arial.

Hopefully this gives you some insight as to where there are additional pixels in your line-heights.

[image: line-height comparison]

Comment: Good guess, but i think it's wrong. If we switch font-families in outer and inner SPANS result is the same. TNR in outer and Arial in inner causes the same increasing line-height on rendering. By the way, when both SPANs font-families are set to TNR or Arial, browser render both variants as 30px line-height. Problem begins when inner and outer SPANs have distinct font-families.

Comment: That's because arial is STILL 2px taller than Times New Roman.  Reversing it is going to have the same effect.  The only different is the inner div with Arial will have 2px more height than the outer div.  You can see this by hovering over the markup of both scenarios in Firebug, and comparing the blue highlighted area of the inner and outer spans.

Comment: "The only different is the inner div with Arial will have 2px more height than the outer div." But if both spans set Arial, text is rendered lower.

Answer (score 0):

The `line-height` value applied is the declared value, as you can see by using developer tools in browsers. The rest is rendering differences that probably have nothing to do with inheritance and are probably not controllable by authors.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is probably not inheritance issue. But i can't understand why setting outer SPAN line-height affects inner SPAN rendering. If we remove line-height from outer and set it to inner everything renders fine. It's real problem, because in our WYSIWYG editor there is guides grid and setting lines height on it to 30px perfectly shows that text is not aligned to grid.