# When a relative line-height is inherited, it is not relative to the element's font-size. Why? And how do i make it relative?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have a global reset that sets `font-size` and `line-height` to `inherit` for every element:

```
* {
  font-size:   inherit;
  line-height: iherit; }
```

For `html`, i define them explicitly:

```
html {
  font-size:   16px;
  line-height: 1.25em; } /* 16×1.25 = 20 */
```

Note, that `line-height` is set in a **relative** unit.

For `h1`, i define different font-size:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 4em; }
```

I expect `h1` to inherit the relative `line-height` of `1.25em`. The resulting line-height should be equal to 80px (16×4×1.25).

But in reality `h1`'s `line-height` remains equal to `20px` (that's the same as `html`'s: 16×1.25=20).

Say, i have the following HTML:

```
<p>foo<br>bar</p>
<h1>foo<br>bar</h1>
```

Screenshot of the result:

[image: relative line height is inherited incorrectly] http://jsfiddle.net/M3t5y/5/

To work around this problem, i have to define `h1`'s `line-height` explicitly equal to the same value that it inherits:

```css
h1 {
  font-size:   4em;
  line-height: 1.25em; }
```

Then `line-height` becomes correct:

[image: issue is worked around by providing line height explicitly rather than inheriting it] http://jsfiddle.net/M3t5y/6/

It looks like the relative value is first calculated into the absolute value and then the absolute value is inherited. Or maybe it is inherited relative to the parent's `font-size`, not the element's `font-size`.

### Questions

1. Why is the relative `line-height` inherited incorrectly?
2. How do make the relative `line-height` be inherited as a value relative to the element's `font-size`, not its parent's?

PS There's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483372/wrong-rendering-of-inherited-line-height) with a similar problem in its title, but it is different in detail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use `em` values for line height, the value of the line height is computed, and it is that computed value which is also used by child elements.

If you use a bare number instead, it is the ratio that is used for the calculation of child element line-heights.

So use `line-height:1.25;` instead of `line-height:1.25em;`

Answer (score 4):

`line-height` is calculated on the element and then that element is inherited when you use `em`. If you inspect your first example you'll notice that the computed value for line-height is `20px` (16x1.25), not `1.25em`.

[image: computed styles]

You can use `line-height:1.25` and it will be computed on the correct element.