# Globally set em letter-spacing is not affected by font-size

Tags: css

I have trouble setting global letter-spacing in my stylesheet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        html {
            letter-spacing: 1em;
        }
        .text {
            /*letter-spacing: 1em;*/
            font-size: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text">My very own text.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So if i don't uncomment letter-spacing at the `.text` selector, it's being converted to 16px instead of expected 50px. Is there a workaround to set letter-spacing once in my `html` selector?

Comment: read how em works and you will understand ;)

Comment: @Temani Afif: It's precisely "how em works" that makes this confusing. It's not because of how em works, but because of how computed values and inheritance work.

Comment: @BoltClock yes and OP expected the em to work on the font size of text and it's working on the global font size (of the html) ...i meant that if he read about how it's working he will understand the behavior :)

Comment: *em = desired element pixel value / parent element font-size in pixels* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i get it now and the solution at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692615/is-it-possible-to-have-letter-spacing-relative-to-the-font-size-and-inherit-prop) works.